# Display tooltip for a selected word

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt, tooltip, pyqt4, pyside

I'm writing a simple text editor using Python 2.7, pyqt library. I basically want to display the meaning of a word when the user selects the word in the text editor.

So far I can detect the word under the cursor, look it up in my dictionary and return the meaning (using a print statement) so I know I can get the guts to work.

My trouble is displaying the meaning of the word in a tooltip that doesn't dissapear in less than 2 miliseconds. So far I have been using this:

```
QtGui.QToolTip.showText(QtGui.QCursor.pos(), tool_tip_text)
```

Ideally want to show the meaning just over where the selection was made, so far this displays the tooltip so quickly that I can't even read the meaning of the word under the cursor. It just pops up and dissapears almost immediately. Can anyone share how to make the tooltip remain visible for at least 5 seconds, or until the user de-selects the word.

I am not using the QHELPEVENT (not even quite sure how the helpevent is triggered) I am just calling my `lookup_word_in_dictionary()` function when a word has been selected.

Any samples are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, I found a solution, creating my own popup class, subclassed from QWidget

and used a simple timer to hide the tooltip

```
QTimer.singleShot(5000, self.hide_tooltip)   #check to see if the tooltip shold be hidden after 5 secs
```

Comment: would you share your solution? How is the `hide_tooltip` defined?

Answer (score 0):

you can replace QToolTip by [QSplashScreen](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsplashscreen.html),if you are Chinese ,please look at [this](http://ogc-daily.blogspot.com/2011/01/x11-selection-translator.html) post .
BTW , can you share the method that you detect the word under the cursor with me ?

Comment: def textUnderCursor(self):
        try:
            
            
            tc = self.textCursor()
            #_word_under_cursor=tc.select(QtGui.QTextCursor.WordUnderCursor)
            tc.select(QtGui.QTextCursor.LineUnderCursor)
            
            LineOfText = unicode(tc.selectedText()) 
            #print "LineOfText = %s " %LineOfText        
   #print "word under cursor = %s " %_word_under_cursor        
        except:
            message=str(sys.exc_info())
            print message

Comment: Yes I just use the amazing Qt API and it works. Sorry I couldn't format the code any better

Comment: I had thought you do it in a system level ,not limited to Qt Apps :)